# Most of my DB questions are about OODBMS/NoSQL. Should I ask them here, or in Stack-Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm in charge of an OODBMS at work, and am generally mostly interested in NoSQL DB. It seems to me that most questions here are about SQL database. But SQL is just one sort of database, and the "About" does not say anything about it. Am I best served by asking my (non-SQL) database-related questions here, or on Stack-Overflow?

Comment: SQL is a standard, not a database.

Comment: I know. I'm not that stupid. Just because I administrate a OODBMS does not mean that I can get away with never using Oracle. My question is, and I think I'm pretty clear about it, are there only DBA of SQL-based administrators hanging around in here, or also people who use MongoDB, Redis, Hadoop, ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO You should feel OK asking about NoSQL here. The DBA StackExchange is like Camelot. You gotta DB Knowledge to bring to the table ? Bring it and we should all live with it.

Your question is living proof that people should expect NoSQL here.

For example, MongoDB is a Database without the relational aspects hard-wired into data retrieval.

Thus far, there are only two questions tagged with MongoDB in the DBA StackExchange:

- [Good Resources on Operating/Administering MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/561/877) (January 11, 2011)
- [CouchDB vs MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/49/877) (January 3, 2011)

Recently, someone ask this question : [What are the benefits of using MySQL Cluster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-mysql-cluster/4139#4139)

In my answer to that question on July 26, 2011, I said this about MySQL Cluster

> In some respects, you have to plan its usage like that of a MongoDB or
>   Cassandra in terms of data layout and sharding

Although a jouneyman in it, I am aware of MongoDB's architecture, I am willing to acknwoledge its usage as a DB, and I can appreciate it to an extent. Admittingly, I have to say that it is out of my comfort zone right now.

Notwithstanding, if you can get the word out to active users of MongoDB so that they can share  their knowledge and experience in the DBA StackExchange, I am sure more NoSQL gurus, RDBMS DBAs that have to work with NoSQL, and just the plain old technologically curious will flock over to this site.

CAVEAT

This question really belongs in https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/ where questions about post content are entertained. Thank you, nonetheless. You get a +1 for your question so that others can see the need to give NoSQL its place here.

AT present, there are only 9 questions tagged as 'nosql', 2 tagged as 'mongodb', and 1 tagged as 'couchdb'. This cannot be overemphasized, but please get the word out for NoSQL gurus to bring it the table here at the DBA StackExchange.

Answer (score 9):

:) I remember seeing mongodb questions. We are more data guys with persistent storage. I think you're safe with these types of questions here! But I could be wrong.

Comment: No, you are not wrong. There were two quesitons posted in the past. You get a +1 for extending a welcome to a NoSQL quesiton in a long time.

Answer (score 4):

I also encourage everyone reading this thread to read the posts here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34343/nosql-databases

and on the related discussion topic:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/why-close-nosql-without-discussion

and pay attention to my conversation with Patrick regarding the fact that this site is about all storage mechanisms, that are not filesystems. If it's about data storage and retrieval mechanisms, as will be used for application level support, then it's valid here. Technically Hadoop questions could be welcome here.

So, that's my $0.02

Comment: More like $2.00. NoSQL just needs more momentum in DBA.SE

Comment: Haha, I always tend to put in a little more extra ;) [I also normally remember to put $0.05]

Comment: I believe [our name](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-database-administrators) contributes to the problem of scaring away people not conversant with the traditional RDBMSs.

Comment: @Nick I know, can you invent a better name and get it disseminated?